# How to integrate samsung pay in ionic 6 app

Tags: ionic-framework, samsung-pay

I am developing an app in ionic 6 framework and i want to integrate Samsung Pay payment gateway in it. I want to get a token from Samsung Pay and will then create a charge in stripe.

So guys, if anyone of you integrated it earlier in Ionic apps, or have knowledge of any available plugin. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/samsung-pay/samsung-pay-api

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need you get the [credentials](https://pay.samsung.com/developers/tour/memberguide), after that, you need to wait until samsung aproves your request. Then download and use the [SDK](https://pay.samsung.com/developers/resource/sdk).
Here's a [GUIDE](https://d3sfvyfh4b9elq.cloudfront.net/ptr/guide/techguide/v1.4/guide/03_00_using_samsung_pay_sdk_apis.html#using_3_1) about how to use it.
The best practices are process, create, and manage payments in Backend

Comment: Is there any ionic 6 plugin for samsung pay.